# Sum a string column in linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a query like that :

```
var q = from i in dbconnect.tblMaterialTenderGroups
   join b in dbconnect.tblMaterials on i.materialId equals b.materialId
   join f in dbconnect.tblFactoryRequests on b.requestId equals f.requestId
   where i.MaterialGroupId == materialGroupId && f.propertyFactoryCenteralId.Contains(facName)
   select b;
```

I am sure that my "q" has a record but when i execute this query:

```
int? sum = q.Sum(g => Int32.Parse(g.requestAmount));
```

I got this Error:

> { System.InvalidOperationException: Could not translate expression 
>    Table(tblMaterialTenderGroup).Join(Table(tblMaterial), i => i.materialId, b =>
>   Convert(b.materialId), (i, b) => new <>f_AnonymousType'2(i = i, b = b)).Join(Table(tblFactoryRequest), <>h_*TransparentIdentifier5 => <>h*_TransparentIdentifier5.b.requestId, f => Convert(f.requestId), (<>h_*TransparentIdentifier5, f) => new
>   <>f*_AnonymousType1'2(<>h_*TransparentIdentifier5
>        = <>h*_TransparentIdentifier5, f = f)).Where(<>h_*TransparentIdentifier6 =>
>   ((<>h*_TransparentIdentifier6.<>h_*TransparentIdentifier5.i.MaterialGroupId == 
>   Invoke(value(System.Func`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]]))) AndAlso 
>   <>h*_TransparentIdentifier6.f.propertyFactoryCenteralId.Contains(Invoke(value(System.Func`1
>   [System.String]))))).Select(<>h_*TransparentIdentifier6 => <>h*_TransparentIdentifier6.
>   <>h__TransparentIdentifier5.b).Sum(g => Parse(g.requestAmount)) into SQL and could not treat it as a local expression.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Int32.Parse` cannot be translated into SQL. Use `Convert.ToInt32` instead:

```
 int? sum = q.Sum(g => Convert.ToInt32(g.requestAmount));
```

Comment: @Spad LINQ to SQL cannot translate any regular .NET method into SQL code. There is only set of methods you can use - like `String.StartsWith` or `Collection.Contains`. Same with converting string to integer

Comment: I have this code: `_payLog.Where(x => x.IsSucceed).Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Price))` and this error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)